# How to print out the properties and methods of a class in GDScript?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I want to print the properties and methods of a class into the console with GDScript. In Python, this can be done with the `print(dir(variable))` method.

Is there an analogous function in GDScript?

Answer (score 6):

I made my own `dir` function and it works OK.

```
func dir(class_instance):
    var output = {}
    var methods = []
    for method in class_instance.get_method_list():
        methods.append(method.name)
    
    output["METHODS"] = methods
    
    var properties = []
    for prop in class_instance.get_property_list():
        if prop.type == 3:
            properties.append(prop.name)
    output["PROPERTIES"] = properties

    return output
```

Comment: this still works well even in Godot 4!